# IntelliJ IDEA 12 Android slow response

Tags: intellij-idea

When I type in the IntelliJ Editor I get major lags from multiple seconds, until my typed word gets displayed.

I'm running IntelliJ with Maven and Git to build Android Projects.

idea.exe, idea64.exe and idea.bat did produce the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to apply the Android SDK in my Project settings.

1. Goto `File | Project Structure | SDKs`
2. Remove all Android related SDK's
3. Add only your default Java JDK like JDK 1.7 (default under: `C:\Program Files\Java\`)
4. Goto the Modules Tab
5. Apply the JDK to all modules or set ProjectSDK as it should now be the JDK1.7

As I tried to solve this problem for several days including adding the IDEA_JDK Variables
I thought sharing this solution could be helpful